# rvm pkg not installing libyaml on MacOSX 10.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I was not being able to create Rails app due to *missing* `libyaml` issue(which is not missing at all). I ran following command after removing all rubies installed by RVM

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

I got following output:

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448'.

Beware, 'rvm pkg ...' is deprecated, read about the new autolibs feature: 'rvm help autolibs'.

Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Fetching yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz to /Users/UserX/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:08 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
There was an error(56).
Checking fallback: ftp://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

    echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc


Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
```

I checked libyaml via Homebrew and it says it's currently installed. Why am I not being able to fetch it?

`rvm -v` gives following:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/UserX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p448'.
rvm 1.25.28 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and realized that the libyaml server that is in the formula is having connection problems.

If you look at the error you got you can see in:

```
Fetching yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz to /Users/UserX/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:08 --:--:--     0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

That you are also having this problem. (`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`)

I was able to find a mirror for this but you will have to edit the brew file.

Run `brew edit libyaml`

In the file comment out the current url and add

```rb
url "http://dfw.mirror.rackspace.com/slackware/slackware64-14.0/patches/source/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.xz"
sha1 'f70b48d7e3696d536c399002d8c6ae9e73d0ac9c'
```

I chose a mirror that was close to me. You can use one of the mirrors on this list:
http://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware64-14.0/patches/source/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.xz.mirrorlist

My final file looks like this:

```rb
require 'formula'

class Libyaml < Formula
  homepage 'http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML'
  # url 'http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz'
  url "http://dfw.mirror.rackspace.com/slackware/slackware64-14.0/patches/source/libyaml/yaml-0.1.6.tar.xz"
  sha1 'f70b48d7e3696d536c399002d8c6ae9e73d0ac9c'

  bottle do
    cellar :any
    sha1 "25a60fa0c77710616018e9b5b013916579147338" => :mavericks
    sha1 "311062934d4bd12ef9881f568dbca21d22bbc8c6" => :mountain_lion
    sha1 "69c062b4beccde415c46048dc77a14f480ba31f3" => :lion
  end

  option :universal

  def install
    ENV.universal_binary if build.universal?

    system "./configure", "--disable-dependency-tracking", "--prefix=#{prefix}"
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

When I ran `brew upgrade libyaml` after that it worked fine and I was able to continue on (in my case I was trying to install ruby 2.1.2)

Hope that helps

--jake

Comment: running `brew upgrade libyaml` says libyaml already installed with latest version

Comment: if you run `brew info libyaml` whats the output?

Comment: says it's already installed with latest version. Somehow I fixed it by reinstalling Ruby